# How to create a 12 word brain wallet seed that is compatible with monero-wallet-cli?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, mnemonic-seed, cold-storage, wallet-recovery

I know there is https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html and https://moneroaddress.org/ but are these good enough rng for creating seed? I hear you could do roll a 6 sided dice 100 times for good randomness, but how would that translate into a seed? lastly how would you restore that 12 word seed in monero-wallet-cli? thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand you want to generate a truly random seed and memorize it, which is good as this would avoid the inherent weakness in human brain's capability to produce randomness.

> I know there is https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html and
>   https://moneroaddress.org/ but are these good enough rng for creating
>   seed?

Probably yes. See [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5aisaz/offline_wallet_generator_dice_d6_version/d9hbfo0/) for some details on how the RNG used works.

> I hear you could do roll a 6 sided dice 100 times for good randomness,
>   but how would that translate into a seed?

If you want to use dice rolls, you could use [this](http://www.jmverse.xyz/monero-stuff/monero-wallet-generator-d6.html) generator, which is a modded version of [moneroaddress.org](https://moneroaddress.org) and gives you the option to use dice rolls practically directly as the seed. Details on how it works can be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5aisaz/offline_wallet_generator_dice_d6_version/). It's reversible, so in theory it's possible to calculate which dice rolls would give a certain seed. Essentially it's just converting between base6 and base16 number representations. Considering it's hosted at a simple site with no https, if you're going to use it, better check the signature or get it straight from github.

The original one could be used but you'd enter dice rolls in the custom entropy field. I think the way it works is that it hashes whatever is inputted there with some rounds of Keccak hash function and uses the result as seed. You could enter anything you want in the custom entropy field. As long as the input has enough entropy, it should be ok.

Now, the result of either of above would be a 256-bit seed, resulting in a 25-word mnemonic. In lieu of a better solution, you could take the first (or last, or middle, or randomly picked) 128-bits of your resulting seed and feed them [here](https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html) to generate the mnemonic, keys and address. I'd still use 256-bits of entropy to generate it though, just in case.

> lastly how would you restore that 12 word seed in monero-wallet-cli?
>   thanks a lot

To restore, you could always start your wallet like this `monero-wallet-cli --generate-from-keys <filename>` and you will be prompted for address, keys and password. If you know the block height when it was created, you could speed up the initial sync by starting it with additional `--restore-height <height>` argument. Need to be sure of the correct  because if you had anything sent to the wallet before the  it will not show it.

Comment: Is there a way to generate those keys with the seed? In case I don't use backup on the private keys?

Comment: You posted the [link](https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html) yourself :) There, you can input your seed mnemonic to the field "1. Mnemonic Seed" and generate everything. Note that those are either 13-word or 25-word because last word is the checksum. The corresponding seeds will be 128-bits and 256-bits. You could also input the "hex" seed directly into field "2. Hexadecimal Seed" and generate the rest of it.

Answer (score 1):

don't use a brain wallet. it's easily guessed.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=foil0hzl4Pg

https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/41618/why-are-brain-wallets-not-secure-people-keep-saying-it-but-explain-to-me-why

Comment: how would 256 bits of random entropy be easily guess? i would only remember the wallet seed not a password like 'This password is really hard to break'.

Comment: if it's random then that's good. using a phrase that's not randomly generated will be broken easily.